# Visual Studio 2008 Extensions for SharePoint Svcs 1.3 missing "Quick Deploy" Menu Item

Tags: sharepoint, deployment, vsewss

We are developing a Sharepoint solution using Visual Studio 2008 Extensions for SharePoint Svcs 1.3.

Some of the developers have had a "Quick Deploy" and a "Package" menu option, some of the developers have never had it. Currently nobody has it.

We are wondering if there is a Guid in the project file that causes this to be available.

Question is how can we get this menu item back again.

Thanks

Shiraz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually solved this.

The root cause of the problem was that some of the developers had an earlier version of vsewss. We lost quick deploy when they merged there changes into the solution file.

We solved it, by creating a new solution file and then adding all of the existing projects to it.